# Problem importing QuartzCore framework into Xcode project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using Xcode 4.

I am trying to import the QuartzCore framework into my Xcode project but I get the following compilation error:

> /Users/sabobin/Desktop/PlayingCard/PlayingCard/PlayingCardViewController.m:10:26:
>   error: Quartz/Quartz.h: No such file
>   or directory
>
> file://localhost/Users/sabobin/Desktop/PlayingCard/PlayingCard/PlayingCardViewController.m:
>   error: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue:
>   'Quartz/Quartz.h' file not found

I navigated to the project target, and selected the Build Phases tab, and then added QuartzCore.framework to the Link Binary With Libraries section.

I then used the following import statement in my view controllers implementation file:

```
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should have

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct line is `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`.

Answer (score 4):

It may help you.

```
#import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering What made you write `#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>` When the framework you are importing is **QuartzCore**.

So the correct one as already pointed out by others is `#import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Answer (score 2):

You no longer need to import QuartzCore as of iOS 7, since it is already included when you "import UIKit".

Answer (score 1):

Should use

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

after importing the QuartzCore.framework from Link Binary With Libraries under Build phase in Xcode.

Comment: Since same answer is accepted, please consider adding comment or edit to previous answer.